# proving identities of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, binary-operations

I am trying to solve the question shown below:
[image]

In order to solve it, first I said $u=1u$ (a property of being a vector space). Then, I grouped the sum $u+(-1)u=1u+(-1)u=u(1+(-1))=0u$.

Now, both parts of question require me to solve $0u$=**0**. I was thinking of maybe using the property: $a(bu)=b(au), u∈ V; a,b∈R$ to prove this identity. Namely, by making $0u=0(1u)=1(0u)$=**0**.

Is that the right way to do it, or are there better ways to prove it? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: **Hint**: $0+0=0$, also remember how $\mathbf{0}$ is defined.

Comment: the 0 vector consists of rows of zeroes only. I am sorry, I still don't get how will that be helpful.

Comment: $\mathbf{0}$ is the unique vector $\in V$ such that $\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{0}=\mathbf{0}+\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{v}$ for all $\mathbf{v}\in V$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$0\vec{u}=(0+0)\vec{u}=0\vec{u}+0\vec{u}.$$
Thus, $$-0\vec{u}+0\vec{u}=-0\vec{u}+(0\vec{u}+0\vec{u})$$ or
$$\vec{0}=(-0\vec{u}+0\vec{u})+0\vec{u}$$ or
$$\vec{0}=\vec{0}+0\vec{u},$$ which gives
$$0\vec{u}=\vec{0}.$$

Now, $$\vec{u}+(-1)\vec{u}=1\vec{u}+(-1)\vec{u}=(1+(-1))\vec{u}=0\vec{u}=\vec{0}.$$

Comment: in the third line, where do we get 0 on the left-hand side (LHS). Also, isn't the 0 that you proved is the real 0, not the zero vector?

Comment: I thought that it's obvious. I'll add. Wait please.

Comment: I did it! See now.

Comment: thank you very much for your help

Comment: You are welcome!